# Multiple Category URLs - Have Category URLs Work Like Product URLs

Tags: magento, url

In Magento, product urls will work in several conditions, for example

```
phones/apple/iphone5.html
phones/iphone5.html
iphone5.html
```

will all serve the iPhone 5 product page.

However, this fallback doesn't work with categories.  How could I make it so that both of the urls

```
phones/apple.html
apple.html
```

would show the Apple category page?